# How to get the page to scroll to the top of a section when that section's id is clicked as a iink

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a section of cards with some info on them. The intended effect is to have the next and previous arrows to scroll up or down to the top of the card(section) id that is on the link. Here is the code html and jquery:

```
        <section  class="backgroundBox" id="2">
             <div class="card">
                   <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-0 right-side smallFontSize top-5112">
                        <h3 class="green">Costs drop significantly as businesses embrace the digital workspace</h3>
                        <p class="center">41% of IT and business decision-makers saw improvements in total management costs by implementing digital workspace efforts, compared with 30% of peers who did not.</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-5 col-sm-offset-1 col-lg-offset-0 center top-52 top-5112">
                     <img src="http:/slideTwo.png" class="img-responsive">
                   </div>
             </div><!-- card --> 
             <div class="bmr-social col-xs-6">
                    <ul class="social-list">
                         <li><a href=""><img src="/social-fb-500.png" alt="facebook" class="img-responsive icon" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
                         <li><a href=""><img src="/social-twitter-500.png" alt="twitter" class="img-responsive icon" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><img src="/social-linkedin-500.png" alt="linkedin" class="img-responsive icon" height="30px" width="30px"></a></li>
                    </ul>
            </div><!-- social -->
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-1 arrows">
                  <p class="right-side social-list"><a href="#1" class="nextPosition up-arrow">&#8593;</a> <a href="#3" class="nextPosition down">NEXT &#8595;</a></p>
           </div><!-- arrows -->
</section>



  <script>
        $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
             $('html, body').animate({
                 scrollTop: $("section").offset().top
              }, 1000);
         });

  </script>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: can you replace image link with sample image link on internet so that it can be loaded perfectly while checking. or can you describe the size of the image in pixels. And you want that at a time only one image should be shown and on clicking next current image should move up and second image should be displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jQuery and a link to a working demo.

```
function scrollToSection(containerID)
{
   var target = $('#' + containerID);

   event.preventDefault();
   $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: target.offset().top
   }, 1000);
}

<button onclick="scrollToSection('section2');">Scroll to Section II</button>
```

http://blog.regencysoftware.com/post/2015/12/09/jQuery-Scroll-To-Position-Demo

Comment: Thanks so much, do you know what would need to be modified to use the <a> tag instead the <button> tag?

Comment: Mike, you can do the following... <a href="#" onclick="scrollToSection('section2');">Click Here </a>